# Leopard Gecko has a injury on her tail

Tags: health, leopard-geckos

I picked her up after a few days of not handling her, and right away I see this on her tail. There is a new "wound"  further up her tail. I'm unsure what to do as I cannot  afford a vet at the moment. I have been cleaning the "wounds" and dabbing betadine on them. Has anyone else experienced anything similar?

It is unlikely these are burns -  her heat lamp is hanging and her floor mat isn't that hot/ she lives alone besides a cricket or 2 for a midnight snack.

Please help I really love her and don't want to lose her. btw her name is lizzo[image]

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't leave live crickets in your geckos enclosure for too long. The crickets are animals, too, with their own needs and survival instincts. If they go hungry, they might start munching on your gecko.

It's general advice to remove crickets that aren't eaten from the enclosure again. One of many sources is [reptile craze](https://reptilecraze.com/can-crickets-hurt-kill-or-eat-leopard-geckos/):

> Brown crickets, *Acheta domestica*, and black crickets, *Acheta assimilis*, are omnivorous insects with strong jaws and teeth. Although crickets are smaller than your geckos, they can bite on their soft parts such as the toes and tail tip, hurting your pets

Crickets aren't capable of killing a gecko like a predator could, but their bites still stress and weaken the geckos and make them vulnerable to infections. It's very likely that a cricket bit the tail of your gecko and it got infected.

Comment: ah. i removed them all i hope this solves the issue/ when i do leave them in i always leave food/water for them