# HELP!!! is my leopard geckos tail infected?

Tags: injury, leopard-geckos, infections

My leopard gecko recently got attacked by my cat. she was left with a scratch on her back and she dropped her tail. the wound on her back is healing good as far as i can tell but the wound from losing her tail is red and has greenish pus coming out. ive never had a leopard gecko drop its tail so im wondering if the pus is a normal part of the healing process or if she has an infection. if she does have an infection going to the vet isn't an option right now so in the meantime what can i do at home to make sure it doesn’t worsen???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Leopard Gecko has a injury on her tail](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/37703/leopard-gecko-has-a-injury-on-her-tail)

Comment: The linked question is different from the current one because the current gecko dropped its tail and OP is unsure whether the drop wound is infected. In the linked question the tail was still attached and the tip of the tail was infected.